# Drag&Drop moving wrong panel

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project that includes several panels. I have 6 panels at the top of the form and 6 panels in 2 columns under those.

I want to drag and drop images from within the top panels to the panels underneath it, vice-versa and between the columns.

However with my current code I have a problem that it sometimes (see reason underneath) moves the wrong panel.

If I drag an image from one of the panels to a new panel and I hover over a panel that already contains an image, my image which I initially dragged will be replaced by the one I just dragged over.

Event code:

```
    private void panel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //we will pass the data that user wants to drag DoDragDrop method is used for holding data
        //DoDragDrop accepts two paramete first paramter is data(image,file,text etc) and second paramter 
        //specify either user wants to copy the data or move data
        source = (Panel)sender;
        DoDragDrop(source.BackgroundImage, DragDropEffects.Copy);

    }


    private void panel_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        //As we are interested in Image data only, we will check this as follows
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Bitmap)))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void panel_DragLeave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        sourcePanel = (Panel)sender;
    }

    private void panel_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        //target control will accept data here
        Panel destination = (Panel)sender;
        destination.BackgroundImage = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Bitmap));
        sourcePanel.BackgroundImage = null;
    }
```

Comment: Any clarification on the "sometimes"?

Comment: @Kilazur With sometimes I meant: "If I drag an image from one of the panels to a new panel and I hover over a panel that already contains an image, my image which I initially dragged will be replaced by the one I just dragged over."

Comment: The initially dragged image is the image contained in the panel, right? To much "drag" for me ;) And from what I understand of the problem, you may not need a dragEnter handler.

Comment: @Kilazur The initially dragged image is the image which I dragged in the first place. After I remove my dragEnter handler I won't be able to drag the images in the panel anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `sourcePanel` in your MouseDown event, not `source` since you never reference `source` again in your posted code.  DragLeave fires when you move the mouse into and out of a panel, so you don't want to be setting your source panel at that moment.

```
void panel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  sourcePanel = (Panel)sender;
  DoDragDrop(sourcePanel.BackgroundImage, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```

and ignore the DragLeave event:

```
void panel_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //sourcePanel = (Panel)sender;
}
```